# Bitbucket cloud API - V 2.0, I need to modify file in script then push it by Bitbucket API v2

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I’m trying to modify some files and push them to the test branch. I didn’t find something in the documentation. can you please anyone tell me how can I do that? and can I push multiple files? (not I’m talking about Bitbucket rest APIv2, not Bitbucket server).